Firebase Main Page Move Issues
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p_ckB-AYUNKQRrFLqRFqSxCUGuUi5AVx/view?usp=sharing
The link above is my Firebase file.
The content of the matter
I tried to test the Firebase local server through the Firebase serve command, but the page can be moved, but only the contents of the index.html file are displayed and the contents of the HTML file in another subpage folder are not visible.
index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Com Study School</h1>
        <nav>
            <!-- <a href="/public/SubPage/Home.html" target="main">Home</a> -->
            <!-- <a href="/public/SubPage/Profile.html" target="main">Profile</a> -->

            <a href="/public/SubPage/Home.html">Home</a>
            <a href="/public/SubPage/Profile.html">Profile</a>
            <a href="/public/SubPage/Gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            <a href="/public/SubPage/member.html">Member</a>
            <a href="/public/SubPage/Study.html">Study</a>

        </nav>
        <hr>
        <!-- <iframe name="main" src="member.html" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0"></iframe> -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>


I tried page 404 on the same path as index.html file and firebase.json as below.
Also, I can't get any information about where the problem is, so I'm not sure what the problem is, so I'm leaving a question.
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}

I'm asking you a question with a translator, so please understand that there may be a strange English context.
Thank you for reading my post with valuable time.
